# Image showing twice in Multi-image slider

Tags: javascript, php, html, slider

I started off trying to just use a plugin for a multi-mage carousel slider for the site. However, there seemed to be some form of problem with every one of them. So i opted to just put up a simple slider myself. All works well except for the fact one of the images displays twice. I know very little about Jquery and would appreciate if someone could point out the simplest fix to stop the image from displaying twice. Oddly enough it is the 3rd image in the HTML (star wars xwing) that displays twice.

The HTML:

```
<div class="featured_menu">
    <div id="mixedSlider">
        <div class="MS-content">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="imgTitle">
                    <h2 class="imgTitle">Warhammer 40,000</h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>/warhammer_40000.jpg" alt="Warhammer 40000">
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac tellus ex. Integer eu fringilla nisi. Donec id dapibus mauris, eget dignissim turpis ...</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="imgTitle">
                    <h2 class="imgTitle">Vallejo</h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>/vallejo.jpg" alt="vallejo paints">
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac tellus ex. Integer eu fringilla nisi. Donec id dapibus mauris, eget dignissim turpis ...</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>               
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="imgTitle">
                    <h2 class="imgTitle">Star Wars X-Wing</h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>/star_wars_x_wing.jpg"alt="Star Wars X-wing">
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac tellus ex. Integer eu fringilla nisi. Donec id dapibus mauris, eget dignissim turpis ...</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>               
            </div>              
            <div class="item">
                <div class="imgTitle">
                    <h2 class="imgTitle">Star Wars X-Wing</h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>/star_wars_x_wing.jpg"alt="Star Wars X-wing">
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac tellus ex. Integer eu fringilla nisi. Donec id dapibus mauris, eget dignissim turpis ...</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>               
            </div>  
            <div class="item">
                <div class="imgTitle">
                    <h2 class="imgTitle">Pokemon</h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>/pokemon.jpg" alt="Pokemon Trading Card Game">
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac tellus ex. Integer eu fringilla nisi. Donec id dapibus mauris, eget dignissim turpis ...</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>               
            </div>  
            <div class="item">
                <div class="imgTitle">
                    <h2 class="imgTitle">Magic the Gathering</h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>/magic_the_gathering.jpg" alt="Magic the Gathering">
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac tellus ex. Integer eu fringilla nisi. Donec id dapibus mauris, eget dignissim turpis ...</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>               
            </div>  
            <div class="item">
                <div class="imgTitle">
                    <h2 class="imgTitle">Dungeons and Dragons</h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>/dungeons_and_dragons.jpg" alt="Dungeons and Dragons">
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac tellus ex. Integer eu fringilla nisi. Donec id dapibus mauris, eget dignissim turpis ...</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>               
            </div>  
            <div class="item">
                <div class="imgTitle">
                    <h2 class="imgTitle">Creature Caster</h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>/creature_caster.jpg" alt="Creature Caster">
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac tellus ex. Integer eu fringilla nisi. Donec id dapibus mauris, eget dignissim turpis ...</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>               
            </div>                  
            <div class="item">
                <div class="imgTitle">
                    <h2 class="imgTitle">Cosmic Encounter</h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>/cosmic_encounter.jpg" alt="Cosmic Encounter">
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac tellus ex. Integer eu fringilla nisi. Donec id dapibus mauris, eget dignissim turpis ...</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>               
            </div>                  
        </div>
        <div class="MS-controls">
            <button class="MS-left"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <button class="MS-right"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src=<?php echo TEMPLATE_PATH;?>/multislider.min.js></script>    
<script>
    $('#mixedSlider').multislider({
        duration: 750,
        interval: 3000
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Let me guess: It is `star_wars_x_wing.jpg` showing twice? Because it is in your code twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove duplicate from your HTML code?

```
<div class="featured_menu">
    <div id="mixedSlider">
        <div class="MS-content">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="imgTitle">
                    <h2 class="imgTitle">Warhammer 40,000</h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>/warhammer_40000.jpg" alt="Warhammer 40000">
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac tellus ex. Integer eu fringilla nisi. Donec id dapibus mauris, eget dignissim turpis ...</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="imgTitle">
                    <h2 class="imgTitle">Vallejo</h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>/vallejo.jpg" alt="vallejo paints">
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac tellus ex. Integer eu fringilla nisi. Donec id dapibus mauris, eget dignissim turpis ...</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>               
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="imgTitle">
                    <h2 class="imgTitle">Star Wars X-Wing</h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>/star_wars_x_wing.jpg"alt="Star Wars X-wing">
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac tellus ex. Integer eu fringilla nisi. Donec id dapibus mauris, eget dignissim turpis ...</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>               
            </div>               
            <div class="item">
                <div class="imgTitle">
                    <h2 class="imgTitle">Pokemon</h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>/pokemon.jpg" alt="Pokemon Trading Card Game">
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac tellus ex. Integer eu fringilla nisi. Donec id dapibus mauris, eget dignissim turpis ...</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>               
            </div>  
            <div class="item">
                <div class="imgTitle">
                    <h2 class="imgTitle">Magic the Gathering</h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>/magic_the_gathering.jpg" alt="Magic the Gathering">
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac tellus ex. Integer eu fringilla nisi. Donec id dapibus mauris, eget dignissim turpis ...</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>               
            </div>  
            <div class="item">
                <div class="imgTitle">
                    <h2 class="imgTitle">Dungeons and Dragons</h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>/dungeons_and_dragons.jpg" alt="Dungeons and Dragons">
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac tellus ex. Integer eu fringilla nisi. Donec id dapibus mauris, eget dignissim turpis ...</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>               
            </div>  
            <div class="item">
                <div class="imgTitle">
                    <h2 class="imgTitle">Creature Caster</h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>/creature_caster.jpg" alt="Creature Caster">
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac tellus ex. Integer eu fringilla nisi. Donec id dapibus mauris, eget dignissim turpis ...</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>               
            </div>                  
            <div class="item">
                <div class="imgTitle">
                    <h2 class="imgTitle">Cosmic Encounter</h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>/cosmic_encounter.jpg" alt="Cosmic Encounter">
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac tellus ex. Integer eu fringilla nisi. Donec id dapibus mauris, eget dignissim turpis ...</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>               
            </div>                  
        </div>
        <div class="MS-controls">
            <button class="MS-left"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <button class="MS-right"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src=<?php echo TEMPLATE_PATH;?>/multislider.min.js></script>    
<script>
    $('#mixedSlider').multislider({
        duration: 750,
        interval: 3000
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ha! and that's why I went to bed after I posted this. Man, do I feel like a Monkey's uncle right about now. I had the exact same trouble with multiple plugins except in their case there was no actual duplicate content it was just repeating the same image three times or leaving a huge blank space in between the loop.